# gyp error when running npm on openshift

Tags: node.js, npm, openshift

I'm deploying to Openshift, running NodeJs v4.2.3 and npm v2.14.7 and keep getting this error. Any ideas how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

```
...
remote: gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]        
remote: make: Entering directory `/var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bufferutil/build'        
remote:   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o        
remote: In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:        
remote: ../../nan/nan.h:43:3: error: #error This version of node/NAN/v8 requires a C++11 compiler        
remote: In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:336: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h: In constructor 'v8::MaybeLocal<T>::MaybeLocal()':        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:353: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h: In member function 'bool v8::MaybeLocal<T>::IsEmpty() const':        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:360: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h: In member function 'bool v8::MaybeLocal<T>::ToLocal(v8::Local<S>*) const':        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:364: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h: In member function 'bool v8::WeakCallbackInfo<T>::IsFirstPass() const':        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:430: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h: At global scope:        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:469: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h: In constructor 'v8::Global<T>::Global()':        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:790: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h: In constructor 'v8::Global<T>::Global(v8::Global<T>&&)':        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:815: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h: In member function 'v8::Global<T>& v8::Global<T>::operator=(v8::Global<S>&&)':        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:827: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h: At global scope:        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:852: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:1089: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:1095: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h: In member function 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Function::NewInstance(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const':        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:3205: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h: In member function 'v8::Local<T> v8::MaybeLocal<T>::ToLocalChecked()':        
remote: /var/lib/openshift/568459e42d52716d5700017b/.node-gyp/4.2.3/include/node/v8.h:7164: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope        
remote: In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:196,        
remote:                  from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16: 
...
```

Comment: Looks like OpenShift is using an outdated g++ version. See also [this request](https://openshift.uservoice.com/forums/258655-ideas/suggestions/7160125--update-the-compiler-chain-gcc5-0).